# Typesafe manipulation of styles in JavaFX

Tags: css, javafx, javafx-2

I want to manipulate CSS style in JavaFX application. Every node has a method setStyle which accepts a String. It works but isn't typesafe. Is there any typesafe way to do the same, i.e. something like this: node.style().setFont(...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not as of JavaFX 2.2.

There is an existing [Jira to provide a CSS object model](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-17293), but it was not exposed as a public API for JavaFX 2.2.

Comment: What is Jira? Do you mean bugtracker request?

Comment: Yes.  I updated the answer to link to the relevant jira request.  (jira requires a login, but anybody can signup at the attached link).